# Need help leveling part of a floor

Tags: floor, level

We had an 8 foot square hottub in our bedroom for 10+ years. Because of the weight, the floor has sagged in that section. The tub is gone now and we had carpeted around it, but now there is a big square spot that has a dip in it. I'd say the dip is at least 1/2 inch. (Our bed is over the spot now)  How can we level it out?

Comment: I suspect you have structural damage to the joists. An 8x8 hottub would likely require the structure to be reinforced before being installed. You're probably lucky that the only thing to happen to the floor is some sagging. I would check the drywall and floor for signs of moisture damage, possibly mold/mildew, since bedrooms typically aren't built for the humidity put off by a hottub.

Comment: Sounds like a very large bedroom, large enough to have required the floor joists be supported mid-span by a wall or beam downstairs.  What is below?  Barring water or moisture damage, I doubt that the weight has caused any structural damage per-se, even more so since you didn't mention the floor having settled at the wall, nor mention the floor being bouncy.  I'd first get a solid measurement of the amount of sag.  If it's less than 1" over 10 feet, I'd place a beam perpendicular to the joists and located under the middle of the sag, then slowly jack it up over the course of a month or two.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way would be to use floor leveling cement. You can built up first with some 1/4 plywood first to get in the ball park.

Without knowing the full extent of damage cause by the hottub I can not suggest a patch job.

Comment: but isn't your suggestion nevertheless just a patch job?

Comment: I was saying if i knew there was not structural damage it could be patched